# Download Word Document from PHP Page of Content not in English

Tags: php, html, ms-word, extract

I am creating a web page were user can download the content of the webpage as a Word document using this code I found online,

```html
<?php
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=document_name.doc");

echo "<html>";
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=Windows-1252\">";
echo "<body>";
echo "<table border='1'><tr><td><b>My document</b></td></tr></table>";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
?>
```

The problem is, I could only use this with English. Once I try the code with content of different language, I get garbage language similar to "Ø£Ù†Ø´Ø·Ø©/ÙØ¹Ø§Ù„ÙŠØ§Øª Ø§Ù„ØªØ·ÙˆÙŠØ± Ø§Ù„Ù…Ø®Ø·Ø· Ù„Ù‡Ø§
ØŒØØ¯Ø¯ Ø·Ø±ÙŠÙ‚Ø© Ø£Ùˆ Ø£ÙƒØ«Ø± Ù„Ù„ØªØ¹Ù„Ù… ÙˆØªØÙ‚ÙŠÙ‚ Ø£Ù‡Ø¯Ø§ÙÙƒ Ø§Ù„Ø®Ø§ØµØ© Ù„Ù„ØªØ¹Ù„Ù… ÙˆØ§Ù„ØªØ·ÙˆØ±
Ù" in the extracted Word document.

Anyone knows where could the problem be or how to fix it ?

Comment: Change the **charset** settings by this `charset=UTF-8`

Comment: OK. Will try that. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @Peacefull Actually, it is UTF-8 already.

Comment: in your example you are using `charset=Windows-1252` ! What is the text that you want to add in your word file ? Give me an example.

Comment: OK. Now it is working. I first thought you mean I should change the encoding type of the word document its self upon open in MS Word. Now the text is readable. Thank you for your help.